# Can't connect to SQL Server Express on Windows 10 outside of Management Studio

Tags: sql-server, windows, jsp, jsf, sql-server-express

I had a working Windows 7 (64bit) system with accessible SQL Server and SQL Server Express instances.  For reasons, I had to reinstall windows and upgraded to windows 10 (64bit).

I tried to install Visual Studio 2005,2008,2010,2012,2013 and SQL Server 2005,2008r2,2012,2014 both in order to restore my SQL set up and make sure I'm not missing anything.  I did have to go back for service packs at SQL Server 2014 stage.

I restored my Netbeans, Glassfish and JSP/JSF projects and wasn't able to connect to the projects using:

url = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433";
and had to use
url = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost\SQLSERVER";

However this is the same model my SQL Server Express used to use:
url = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost\SQLEXPRESS";

And this no longer works.

I am able to log into both instances via Management Studio and recreated my dbs.
My services are finally starting automatically and they show the above names with the service.
I have the same problems with my firewall off, so that shouldn't be an issue.

In Configuration Manager, I do not show this "protocols for sqlexpress" I keep seeing people mention.

How can I get access to my SQLExpress instance outside of Management Studio?

Connection information is as follows:

```
driver = "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver";
url = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost\\SQLEXPRESS";
dbName = ";DatabaseName=Test";
dbUsername = "SA";
dbPassword = "password";

connect = Method.openConnection(driver, url, dbName, dbUsername, dbPassword);
```

Comment: Is the other an full licensed MSSQL Installation?

Comment: Jsf or jsp does not make the connections to a server. Check drivers etc…

Comment: Andreas,

As far as I know, the SQLServer instance is not an express instance, so I would assume it counts as licensed.

Comment: Kukeltje, the two connections are using the same drivers, settings, etc. except for the service name: SQLSERVER vs SQLEXPRESS.

My point in mentioning JSP/JSF is that is how I'm testing it.  Editing original with connection data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a while ago I solved this and forgot to answer, but I believe I ended up reinstalling only the latest possible versions of SQLServer instead of trying to install as far back as 2005 and upgrade from there.

In the SQL Server Configuration Manager for 2014, I was able to see and change the protocols for my SQL Server instances.

My express Configuration Manager....is still broken, but is ultimately unnecessary.

For the record, I don't think anyone who helped was wrong, but we just hadn't investigated deep enough at the time.